# can't upload attachement with has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, has-one

Hi I am having issues with `paperclip` with a `has_one` association:

#### `track.rb`

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lesson

  has_attached_file :track,
                :path => ":rails_root/public/system/lessons/tracks//:id/:basename.:extension",
                :url => "/system/lessons/tracks/:id/:basename.:extension"
  validates :track,
        attachment_content_type: { content_type: [ 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg',
                                                   'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3',
                                                   'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3',
                                                   'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg',
                                                   'audio/x-mpegaudio' ]}
end
```

#### `lesson.rb`

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :track , dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :track, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

#### `lessons_controller`

```
def new
  @lesson = Lesson.new
  @levels = Level.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
end

def lesson_params
  params.require(:lesson).permit(:title, :content, :level_id, :video_id,  :bpm,
                                 :artist, track_attributes: [:id, :track])
end
```

#### `_form.html.slim`

```
= form_for @lesson, :class => 'form-horizontal', html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  = f.fields_for :track, :html => {:multipart => true} do |t|
      = t.file_field :track
```

#### `migration track`

```
class CreateTracks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tracks do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
      t.has_attached_file :track
    end
  end
end
```

#### `migration lessons`

```
class CreateLessons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :lessons do |t|

      t.timestamps null: false
      t.string :title
      t.string :artist
      t.text :content
      t.string :video_id
      t.integer :bpm
      t.references :track, index: true
      t.references :level, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

So my upload field displays only if I replace `fields_for :track` with `fields_for :tracks` in my form but then I get an error : `unpermitted parameter`.

Any ideas of where the problem could be coming from?

Comment: You need to permit nested attributes including id of nested object.

Comment: isnt that what I did with : track_attributes: [:id, :track] ?

Comment: Yes. You can't use tracks with has_one association. And in above code is alignment is missing? fields_for should nested in form_for.

Comment: I edited my code (just miss aligned during the creation of this topic) but the file upload still won't display when I put fields_for :track instead of fields_for :tracks in the form.

Comment: Does paperclip work with has_one relationships ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works but you need to build nested object as follows:

```
@lesson.build_track
```

Add above line into your controller. It will show file input field for track in given form.